# FaceClient missing from Azure Face Recognition

Tags: python-3.x, azure, artificial-intelligence, face-recognition

I'm trying to make some test with Azure Face Recognition but when I installed the module with `pip install azure-cognitiveservices-vision-face`, it is failing to find the `FaceClient` class and moreover `from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face` is missing from imports.

How do I import the correct module?